# Open xgmml file extension of the graph of arangoDB

Tags: graph, arangodb, cytoscape

How to open .xgmml file?
I have exported the graph from arango using arangoexport, the extension is .xgmml
I need to know: how can I open this file?
I have tried cytoscape, but it doesn't work, it messages me that cannot recognize .xgmml file.

Comment: How did you try to open it in Cytoscape? Which version of Cytoscape?

Comment: I download it from the website, version 3.6.1
when I tried to open the .xgmml file from arango it gives me a message box that cannot recognize the file extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get this error message:

[image: Cytoscape does not recognize files with suffix .xgmml]

then you probably tried to open your `.xgmml` file with the *Open Session* button: [image: Folder icon]

This is the same as *File > Open...* in the menu. It only opens Cytoscape `*.cys` files.

To load a graph from an XGMML file, you need to use the *Import Network From File* button: [image: Import graph icon]

This is the same as *File > Import > Network > File...* in the menu. It supports various formats, including `*.xgmml`:

[image: Cytoscape import network dialog]

Select your file and open it. It should load the graph without problems.